# pandas series: change order of index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` series:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3], index = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

How can I change the order of the index, so that `s` becomes

```
B    2
A    1
C    3
```

I tried

```
s['B','A','C']
```

but I get a KeyError.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas.Series.reindex):

```
In [52]:

s = s.reindex(index = ['B','A','C'])
s
Out[52]:
B    2
A    1
C    3
dtype: int64
```