# How can I prevent stack from sorting indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a test dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group1": ["X", "Y", "Y", "X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y"],
    "Group2": ["A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"],
    "Number1": [1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 3],
    "Number2": [6, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 6, 8],
})
df2 = df1.pivot_table(index="Group1", columns="Group2", margins=True)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
           Number1                       Number2                         
Group2       A    B         C       All         A    B         C       All
Group1                                                                    
X          1.0  3.0       NaN  2.333333  6.000000  4.0       NaN  4.666667
Y          4.0  NaN  4.000000  4.000000  7.000000  NaN  4.500000  5.750000
Z          NaN  NaN  2.000000  2.000000       NaN  NaN  2.000000  2.000000
All        3.0  3.0  3.333333  3.125000  6.666667  4.0  3.666667  4.875000
```

When I call `stack` on this dataframe, I get this result:

```
df3 = df2.stack()
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
                Number1   Number2
Group1 Group2                    
X      A       1.000000  6.000000
       All     2.333333  4.666667
       B       3.000000  4.000000
Y      A       4.000000  7.000000
       All     4.000000  5.750000
       C       4.000000  4.500000
Z      All     2.000000  2.000000
       C       2.000000  2.000000
All    A       3.000000  6.666667
       All     3.125000  4.875000
       B       3.000000  4.000000
       C       3.333333  3.666667
```

How can I prevent `stack` from sorting the indices so that the order of `Group2` remains as `A, B, C, All`?

Comment: please provide exact command you have used

Comment: This doesn't prevent alphabetical sort, but it fixes the issue [pandas series: change order of index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212214/pandas-series-change-order-of-index). `df3 = df3.reindex(index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'All'], level=1)`.

Comment: see this issue on github [sort=False to stack/unstack/pivot](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15105) you could create a categorical index before unstacking

Comment: Ideally, I would have liked to do this without specifying an order manually, but if these are the only ways, I'll just use a categorical index or `reindex`.

Comment: the issue above is welcoming any contributions so feel free to add to the pandas api :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, We need [`pd.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
df2.stack().reindex(df2.columns.get_level_values(1).unique(), level='Group2')
```

---

```
                Number1   Number2
Group1 Group2                    
X      A       1.000000  6.000000
       B       3.000000  4.000000
       All     2.333333  4.666667
Y      A       4.000000  7.000000
       C       4.000000  4.500000
       All     4.000000  5.750000
Z      C       2.000000  2.000000
       All     2.000000  2.000000
All    A       3.000000  6.666667
       B       3.000000  4.000000
       C       3.333333  3.666667
       All     3.125000  4.875000
```

We can use `level='Group2'` or `level=1`

Answer (score 0):

Use the function argument `sort=False` in the version > 2.2

[pandas.DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)